# Powershell: Duplicate a Directory

Tags: powershell

I have a directory on the source server which I want duplicated on a target server in its entirety.  On the target server, the directory already exists with some other files/directories, but I want them removed automatically since it would not match my source directory exactly.  I do not want to delete the destination directory.

Comment: Sounds like a robust file copy should be used. [`robocopy <source> <destination> /mir`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I second Mad's comment especially if _in its entirety_ means security structure as well. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So true, better than reinventing the wheel....

Answer (score 1):

They easiest way is probably [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx). See also [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/129098/how-to-get-robocopy-running-in-powershell) for discussion on using it in Powershell.

[`rsync(1)`](https://rsync.samba.org/) is probably the fastest option. You can get a [Windows port here](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html). You can read the man page here: https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html